# Why Can't I Use a Gamma Disribution for the main f(y|theta) in rjags

Tags: r

I have a distribution of response data y[i] that looks like a gamma distribution more than a normal distribution, so I thought I could develop the alpha and beta from the mean of a linear regression equation and the the assumed variance from the prior gamma.

Moreover, in all of the valid examples I can find, no one ever seems to use a gamma distribuiton for anything other than the priors

SO, here is the code using the normal distribution that works:

```
library("car")  
data("Leinhardt")  
?Leinhardt  
str(Leinhardt)  
head(Leinhardt)  
dat = na.omit(Leinhardt)  
dat$logincome = log(dat$income)  
dat$loginfant = log(dat$infant)  
str(dat)  




library("rjags")  
    

mod_string = " model {  
for (i in 1:length(y)) {  
y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], prec)  
mu[i] = a[region[i]] + b[1]*log_income[i] + b[2]*is_oil[i]  
}  
    
for (j in 1:max(region)) {  
a[j] ~ dnorm(a0, prec_a)  
}  
    
a0 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1.0e6)  
prec_a ~ dgamma(1/2.0, 1*10.0/2.0)  
tau = sqrt( 1.0 / prec_a )  
    
for (j in 1:2) {  
b[j] ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1.0e6)  
}  
    
prec ~ dgamma(5/2.0, 5*10.0/2.0)  
sig = sqrt( 1.0 / prec )  
} "  
    
set.seed(116)  
data_jags = list(y=dat$loginfant, log_income=dat$logincome,  
                 is_oil=as.numeric(dat$oil=="yes"), region=as.numeric(dat$region))  
data_jags$is_oil  
table(data_jags$is_oil, data_jags$region)  

params = c("a0", "a", "b", "sig", "tau")  

mod = jags.model(textConnection(mod_string), data=data_jags, n.chains=3)  
update(mod, 1e3) # burn-in  

mod_sim = coda.samples(model=mod,  
                       variable.names=params,  
                       n.iter=5e3)  
    
mod_csim = as.mcmc(do.call(rbind, mod_sim)) # combine multiple chains
```

And then, here is the modification to the above that I tried that I cannot get to work:

```
mod_string2 = " model {  
for (i in 1:length(y)) {  
y[i] ~ dgamma(alpha[i],beta[i])  
mu[i] = a[region[i]] + b[1]*log_income[i] + b[2]*is_oil[i]  
alpha[i]=mu[i]^2/prec  
beta[i]=mu[1]/prec  
}  
     
for (j in 1:max(region)) {  
a[j] ~ dnorm(a0, prec_a)  
}  
    
a0 ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1.0e6)  
prec_a ~ dgamma(1/2.0, 1*10.0/2.0)  
tau = sqrt( 1.0 / prec_a )  
    

for (j in 1:2) {  
b[j] ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1.0e6)  
}  
    
prec ~ dgamma(5/2.0, 5*10.0/2.0)  
sig = sqrt( 1.0 / prec )  
} "
```

Here is the error message (I have no clue what this means, and there is no reference I can find):

"Error in jags.model(textConnection(mod_string2), data = data_jags, n.chains = 3) :
Error in node y[1]
Invalid parent values"

#### Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I suspect it means you have observed values (in `y`) that are invalid for a Gamma distribution.  Given all you've done is change from Normal to gamma, obvious candidates are negative values.  You've shared your code, but not your data, so your example is not reproducible.

Comment: First: Thank You!  Here is the y data:

Comment: Here is some of the y data(there are no negative valuess):   
       y=dat$loginfant:  
  3.284664 3.165475 2.833213 2.821379 2.602690 2.312535 2.557227 3.015535 
        2.879198 3.246491 2.459589 2.451005 2.785011  
 2.424803 3.802208 4.269697 2.261763 2.549445 2.862201 2.867899 4.457830 
      4.363099 4.828314 3.335770 5.703782 4.060443  
 6.476972 3.945458 4.087656 5.135798 4.356709 4.139955 3.996364 3.887730 
         3.325036 4.370713 3.095578 3.265759 2.610070

Comment: The first example(the one that worked) was copied from a course i took, and the second is the same example with my changes. I have a few books that have examples, too, but none of the examples show using a gamma distribution for anything other than a prior. I suspect that a gamma distribution may have fundamental problems when you try to use it in Markov Chains, but this is just my guess.